# Performancepoint cascading filter connection formula in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, performancepoint

I have dimension with hierarchy A - B and a time dimension.

I have made 3 different filters from that dimension in Performancepoint 2010, to use as **cascading filters**.

Cascading works fine, but sometimes dimension members are **valid depending on the time dimension** and cascading filters will give many "empty" members.

Ie. Jan 2010 only B1,B2 and B3 show measures, others members (B4,B5..) show empty.

How i can connect time dimension to cascading filters so it will only show the valid members at that current time?

Comment: NonEmpty function in MDX queries can help you? What have you tried so far?

Comment: for B-level members i tried:
nonempty(<<UniqueName>>, [Time].[Year].&[2010]), uniquename being the A-level of the hierarchy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it using [NonEmptyCrossjoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144797.aspx) - MDX function.

This function returns a set that contains the cross product of one or more sets, excluding empty tuples and tuples without associated fact table data.